# How to multiply all values in a data frame column depending on the column's name?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the following data:

```
Species Aug-16  Sep-16  Aug-17  Sep-17
Cat 740 69  758 443
Dog 783 559 230 143
Lizard  294 965 718 938
```

I would like to multiply each variable in the data frame's column by `0.5` **IF** that column's name has the word `"Sep"` in it.

Answer (score 2):

in base R:

```
df1[grepl("Sep",names(df1))] <- 0.5* df1[grepl("Sep",names(df1))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I only saw 'Sep', if it is 'September' change Sep to September in `str_detect` function

```
library(stringr)

df[,str_detect(names(df),'Sep')]=df[,str_detect(names(df),'Sep')]*0.5
df
  Species Aug.16 Sep.16 Aug.17 Sep.17
1     Cat    740   34.5    758  221.5
2     Dog    783  279.5    230   71.5
3  Lizard    294  482.5    718  469.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for "Sep" likes the following:

```
library(dplyr)
col_names <- names(df %>% select(contains("Sep")))
df[,col_names] = df[,col_names]*0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

A dplyr option:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(Species = c("Cat", "Dog", "Lizard"), 
                     `Aug-16` = c(740L, 783L, 294L), 
                     `Sep-16` = c(69L, 559L, 965L), 
                     `Aug-17` = c(758L, 230L, 718L), 
                     `Sep-17` = c(443L, 143L, 938L)), 
                .Names = c("Species", "Aug-16", "Sep-16", "Aug-17", "Sep-17"), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Sep')), funs(. * .5))

df2
#>   Species Aug-16 Sep-16 Aug-17 Sep-17
#> 1     Cat    740   34.5    758  221.5
#> 2     Dog    783  279.5    230   71.5
#> 3  Lizard    294  482.5    718  469.0
```